# Explain the effect of a parent column in a nested select

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario where I need to delete rows from a table using the outcome of a nested select.  Like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl_big TABLE (bigID int);

INSERT INTO @tbl_big (bigID) 
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

DECLARE @tbl_small TABLE (smallID int);

INSERT INTO @tbl_small (smallID) 
VALUES (1),(2),(3);

DELETE FROM @tbl_big 
WHERE (bigID IN (SELECT smallID FROM @tbl_small));

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl_big; -- shows 4,5 as expected
```

However, during development I accidentally made a typo:

```
DELETE FROM @tbl_big WHERE (bigID IN (SELECT bigID FROM @tbl_small));  --bigID used instead of smallID

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl_big; -- no rows
```

The result was that **all** rows within the parent table were deleted.

While this *may* be completely acceptable T-SQL, I've never seen it applied like this, nor would I expect the statement to even compile given that `@tbl_small` does not contain a `bigID` column.

Can anybody please clarify why/how this works, and is it valid T-SQL?  Also, can you provide a real-world example where this is more useful than risky(!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bigID` in the `DELETE` statement you mentioned referes to @tbl_big because it is legal to mention columns from the main table in the sub queries you write in the `WHERE` clause. For example, you can write the below:
`DELETE FROM @tbl_big WHERE (bigID IN (SELECT smallID FROM @tbl_small WHERE smallID = bigID));`

So, in your case, you just used all bigID values in your table in the sub query as a constant value.

Comment: Okay thanks.  I just realised that this also works fine `DELETE FROM @tbl_big WHERE (bigID IN (SELECT bigID));`. Although both our `Delete` statement examples are legibly obvious in what they're trying to achieve, I think it seems risky to allow the parent column to be used as I have done in my original post.  I guess it comes down to coding style preference, although would like a real-world case where this added more value than fully specifying the sub-query